# Is it possible to trace/record every file IO being done by one or all applications, both through syscalls and mmap?

Tags: filesystems, tracing

I want to trace every IO operation an application does in its lifetime and don't want any caching effect to interfere. I cannot change the application source code, using a shim would be OK. Performance is not an issue, I just want to record what an application does even if it takes hours.
The final goal of this is to use the traces to try to improve heuristics related to filesystems, for example, prefetching.
Ideally the output would be something like <filename, offset>, but just  would  probably be enough.

Here are my ideas so far and why I think they won't work:

1. Trace all block-level accesses, for example, IOs sent to an SSD. This requires disabling readahead and page cache. The former is easy to do, the latter seems to be impossible. Flushing the page cache every X units of time is out of the question since there is no guarantee every read bypasses the page cache. Disabling only write-cache is also not enough.
2. Using eBPF to trace all filesystem operations, like [this article does](https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2018/11/21/gaining-ebpf-vision-tracing-linux-filesystem-disk-requests/). There are two issues here: apparently only the first request of a file is recorded (from the blog: "The probe we implemented ... identify the first time a block is requested"), <s>and I wrote a replica of what the blog does and the reads are not printed out</s>Source is here][2](https://github.com/hfingler/ebpf-io-traces) (edit: the reason why it wasn't showing is that the file I was reading was on an NFS drive. Whoops).
   The BCC script shows some IOs happening on the system, but none from the `touchblk` application are printed out. I have no idea why or how.

Edit: here are some other ideas, but I don't know how to implement yet:

3. Always mark pages as unavailable, so that they are always fetched from disk.
4. TLB poisoning.

Am I overthinking this? Is there either a solution that I didn't think about that does this or a fix to one of the problems I identified?

Thanks!

Comment: `strace` might be an pretty good approximation. But note that something as simple as `open()` will generate different amounts of I/O depending on the filesystem having `atime` or not. And it would be pretty hard to trace that from the application, because it is happening, well, inside the filesystem, and it is probably going to be cached by the kernel, that has already read the directory entry.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. What are you really trying to accomplish? Turning your system into a very poorly configured one as a first step seems unwise.  What are "heuristics related to filesystems" that you wish to "improve"? What's your real goal?

Comment: @waltinator That's the real goal. I want to have IO traces of different applications (e.g. kernel building) so I can experiment with different, more complex read-ahead mechanisms, and simulate how well they would work.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani strace wouldn't show any mmap'd reads. I can't asssume the applications I want to collect traces of only use syscalls, unfortunately.

Comment: `installwatch`, part of the `checkinstall` package, shows how, using `LD_PRELOAD`, you can intercept all system calls, so you could adapt this to insert monitoring code in front of any I/O calls. Use the source!

Comment: @waltinator unfortunately that approach doesn't capture I/O reads of mmap'd files that hit the page cache, only syscall reads. I came up with a solution to this issue using userfaultfd. So through a LD_PRELOAD shim for read syscalls and a custom mmap I can capture all I/Os.